# how to replace all using regexp (javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

```
var text = "&#39;Hello&#39;World&#39;&#39;&#39;";
```

how to replace all `&#39;` and `Hello` and `World` to '

```
result = "'''''''"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
text.replace(/&#39;|Hello|World/g, "'")
```

The `g` is for global, it wont stop at the first match but continue matching as many times as possible.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to replace `&#39;`, `Hello`, `World` with `"` instead of `'`? Change the last argument to `"\""`.